# CRUD with AngularJS and PHP

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, crud

I have the following code:

```
var carregarUsuario = function () {
    $http.get("buscar.php").then(function (retorno){
        console.log(retorno.data);
        $scope.usuarios = retorno.data;
    });
};
carregarUsuario();
```

PHP:

```
error_reporting(0);
$user = "root";
$password = "";
$db = "angulardb";
$host = "localhost";
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", $user, $password, $db);
if (mysqli_connect_errno()){
  echo "Erro: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }
$usuario = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT *  FROM users");

    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    $return = array();

    while ($dados = mysqli_fetch_assoc($usuario)) {
        array_push($return, $dados);
    }

    echo json_encode($return);
```

No data is being displayed on the console or on the page. How do I resolve this?

**UPDATE**

When you place a `print_r` in my PHP code, just after the `while` I have (in .php page):

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2
            [id] => 2
            [1] => João Silva
            [nome] => João Silva
            [2] => joao.silva@angular.com
            [email] => joao.silva@angular.com
            [3] => 123456
            [pass] => 123456
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 3
            [id] => 3
            [1] => Mario de Almeida
            [nome] => Mario de Almeida
            [2] => mario.almeida@angular.com
            [email] => mario.almeida@angular.com
            [3] => 123456
            [pass] => 123456
        )

)
```

Using only console.log (retorno) I have:

```
Object {data: "", status: 200, config: Object, statusText: "OK"}
```

No data is being displayed on the console or on the page. How do I resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. Apparently the error was in the collation of the database . The bank was like latin, moved to utf8 and functioned normally . thank you

Answer (score 0):

Dude, u cannot echo array. Use `print_r(json_decode($array))`.

```
var carregarUsuario = function () {
    $http.get("buscar.php").then(function (retorno){
        console.log(retorno.data);
        $scope.usuarios = retorno.data;
    });
 return $scope.usuarios
};
carregarUsuario();
```

Also ur function does not return nothing.

Comment: Using print_r(json_decode($return))  json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in ///// Using print_r(json_decode($return), returns nothing